Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 warning message bubble closing/minimizing
I have recently upgraded Android Studio to Koala (2024.1.1)
Working on Flutter project (though I am not sure it makes a difference)
Whenever I see a warning (dashed yellow underline) and hovering on it , the warning description and suggestions appear for a split of a second and then minimizes automatically.
The minimized bubble window describes the problem but the suggestions disappear.


I can obviously click the bulb on the left of the edit window or to go to dart analysis tab, but it is less comfortable.

I came here as I was suffering this on flutter debugging, but I think I have the solution for you, needed to find the specific menu going through all the settings, to 'remove' it (or hide to not show) you just need to:
Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data Views
There you just need to uncheck the second option like the following image:
Value Tooltip disabled
